# Elastic File System vs S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a distributed application where a process uploads a file to S3 and other (one or more) process downloads and work on the file. These process now upload their output file to S3 which other process can use.
I am currently using S3 for storing this file - which causes high latency for uploading/downloading larger files.
The applications all run on EC2 instances.
Will EFS be a better use case for modeling this? Will there be latency improvement on using EFS as opposed to S3. Also, will EFS be equally reliable as S3?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AWS EFS vs EBS vs S3 (differences & when to use?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29575877/aws-efs-vs-ebs-vs-s3-differences-when-to-use)

Comment: You should ask AWS directly with this new service.