# AWS EC2 doesn't display instance usage report. Why?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I use AWS EC2 free tiers and Elastic Beanstalk. I didn't buy any services from AWS yet.

When I login as a root, AWS informs me that I'm going to exceed the Free Tier usage limit:

[image]

I want to see the report. I do all that this docs says https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/usage-reports-instance.html#viewing-instance-usage
But AWS doesn't show me reports. I set all the necessary filters correctly:

[image]

Why? How to make AWS to show report?

Comment: It's warning you about S3, and you are running a usage report on EC2. Those are two separate services. You need to look at your S3 usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured that out.

I have never used any AWS storage services explicitly yet. I only test Elastic Beanstalk now to have my hands on AWS. Docs says Beanstalk in free, you only pay for AWS resources that Beanstalk uses. And Beanstalk always created free `t2.micro` instance for my Node.js web server and I never had over-limit requests to my sample test apps. However I often uploaded new versions of my apps as `.zip` bundles. And that Elastic Beanstalk charged me for that! In November it suddenly charged me $2 for `S3` usage. I never used `S3`, but Beanstalk did it. Silently.

Be careful playing with Beanstalk. Beanstalk makes all those PUT requests to `S3` behind the scenes.

It it better to use `EC2 instance` with `EBS storage`. EBS offers for free:

> 2 000 000 I/O operation (S3 only 20 000 GET, 2000 PUT)
>
> 30 Gb storage (S3 only 5Gb)
>
> 1 Gb for snapshots (S3 doesn't)

For development and test environments free `EBS General Purpose (SSD)` is good enough. But Beanstalk doesn't use it. It uses expensive `S3`.