# Best AWS setup for a dedicated FTP server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ftp

My company is looking for a solution for file sharing via FTP - currently, we share one server for client/admin FTP file sharing and serving multiple sites, and are looking to split off our roles so that we have one server dedicated to FTP and one for serving websites.

I have tried to find a good solution with AWS, but cannot find any detailed information regarding EBS and EC2 servers, and whether an EC2 package will be able to handle FTP storage.  For example, a T2.nano instance seems ideal with 1 cpu and minimal RAM, but I see no information regarding EBS storage limits.

We need around 500GiB at most, and will have transfers happening daily in the neighborhood of 1GiB in and out.  We don't need to run a database or http server.  We may run services for file cleanup in the background weekly.

**EDIT:**

I mis-worded the question, which was founded from a fundamental lack of understanding AWS EC2 and EBS which I now grasp.  I know EC2 can run FTP services, the question was more of a cost-effective solution with dynamic storage.  Thanks for the input!

Comment: Did you check another similar questions??? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23939179/ftp-sftp-access-to-an-amazon-s3-bucket

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to use S3 - I need normal FTP access via a GUI with permissions, etc so the non-tech people don't need to run specialized setups.  Also, I have third party companies accessing particular resources on this server as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052875/setting-up-ftp-on-amazon-cloud-server) is among the most seen on SO for aws: You can install a FTP server on any EC2 instance type

There's no limit on EBS and you can always [increase the storage](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-expand-volume.html) if you need, so best rule is: start low and increase when needed

Only point to mention is the network performance comes with the instance type so if you care about the speed a t2.nano ([low network performance](http://www.ec2instances.info/)) might not be sufficient

Comment: This is the solution we are going with - thank you.  I had a mental disconnect in understanding AWS for some reason, but I now understand how EBS and EC2 instance works.  Cheers!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29575877/aws-efs-vs-ebs-vs-s3-differences-when-to-use

Answer (score 4):

As others here on SO will tell you: don't bother with EBS. It can be made to work but does not make much sense in the long run. It's also more expensive and trickier to operate (backups/disaster recovery/having multiple ftp server machines).

Go with S3 storing your files and use something that is able to leverage S3 for ftp (like s3fs)

See:
http://resources.intenseschool.com/amazon-aws-howto-configure-a-ftp-server-using-amazon-s3/

[Setting up FTP on Amazon Cloud Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052875/setting-up-ftp-on-amazon-cloud-server)

http://cloudacademy.com/blog/s3-ftp-server/

If FTP is not a strong requirement you can also look at migrating people to using S3 directly (either initially or after you do the setup and give them the option of both FTP and S3 directly)

Comment: Unfortunately, I had researched this very solution but we have non-tech-savvy users that will be using this on and off, in and out of office, as well as third party companies who pull content.