# Which AWS service is best for Static files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-efs

Which AWS service is best for static content - HTML, JavaScript, Images, JSON, PDF, Excel, Text files and Application Logs.

> S3 or EFS or EBS

Price is not an issue, but looking for most reliable, secure and high throughput (Mine is US only webapp).

Comment: Note that CloudFront does not *store* your files.  They have to be stored elsewhere -- CloudFront will fetch, cache, and serve them from their authoritative origin, but CloudFront itself is designed as a non-durable, ephemeral cache (and it doesn't charge you for what it transiently stores while performing that role).  CloudFront is used *with* one of the other options (very commonly, S3).

Answer (score 1):

*[Trying not to be opinionated here]*

Generally speaking, S3 is the default choice for these criteria.

S3 is:

- way cheaper than EFS
- more durable than EBS (using standard class)
- (somewhat) maintenance-free, doesn't require deploying instances etc.
- has built-in security features that would be enough for most applications
- works well with CloudFront for distribution and acceleration

Answer (score 1):

S3 is the right and the most obvious choice here. Mainly because of its price (up to 10 times cheaper compared with EFS and up to 4 times cheaper compared with EBS) but secondly because it's designed to serve static website (or static content).

Also
[Check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29575877/aws-efs-vs-ebs-vs-s3-differences-when-to-use)