# S3 or EFS - Which one is best to create dynamic image from set of images?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-efs

I have a quiz site which creates images from a set of source images, the result images are stored in S3 and i don't care about it. My question is about source images, S3 or EFS is better for storing the source images for this purpose. I am using php to create result images.

Comment: If you're already using S3 then you can just stick with that. If you're using both already then EFS would feel more native when writing the PHP code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a general rule for you: **Always use Amazon S3** unless you have a reason to do otherwise.

Why?

- It has unlimited storage
- The data is replicated for resilience
- It is accessible from anywhere (given the right permissions)
- It has various cost options
- Can be accessed by AWS Lambda functions

The alternative is a local disk (EBS) or a shared file system (EFS). They are more expensive, can only be accessed from EC2 and take some amount of management. However, they have the benefit that they **act as a directly-attached storage device, so your code can reference it directly without having to upload/download**.

So, if your code needs the files locally, the EFS would be a better choice. But if you code can handle S3 (download from it, use the files, upload the results), then S3 is a better option.

Answer (score 1):

Given your source images will (presumably) be at a higher resolution than those you are creating, and that once processed, they will not need to be accessed regularly after while (again, presumably), I would suggest that the lower cost of S3 and the archiving options available there means it would be best for you. There's a more in depth answer here:

[AWS EFS vs EBS vs S3 (differences & when to use?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29575877/aws-efs-vs-ebs-vs-s3-differences-when-to-use)

Comment: If i use S3 for source images it require more bandwidth right ?
If i use efs there is no extra cost for bandwidth ?

Comment: Is your app server in AWS as well? I think data transfer from EC2 to S3 is free within the same region, and also free from the public internet: https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/

Comment: Yes, my app is in Ec2.